# SSIS flat file with joins

Tags: sql-server, ssis, foreign-keys, etl, lookup

I have a flat file which has following columns

- Device Name
- Device Type
- Device Location
- Device Zone

Which I need to insert into SQL Server table called Devices.
Devices table has following structure

- DeviceName
- DeviceTypeId (foreign key from DeviceType table)
- DeviceLocationId (foreign key from DeviceLocation table)
- DeviceZoneId (foreign key from DeviceZone table)

DeviceType, DeviceLocation and DeviceZone tables are already prepopulated. 
Now I need to write ETL which reads flat file and for each row get DeviceTypeId, DeviceLocationId and DeviceZoneId from corresponding tables and insert into Devices table. 
I am sure this is not new but its being a while I worked on such SSIS packages and help would be appreciated.

Comment: Flat File Source -> Lookup Component -> A) OLE DB Command for Updates or B) OLE DB Destination to a staging table + Execute SQL Task to merge the data

Answer (score 0):

Load the flat content into a staging table and write a stored procedure to handle the inserts and updates in T-SQL.

Having FK relationships between the destination tables, can probably make a lot of trouble with a single data flow and a multicast.
The problem is that you have no control over the order of the inserts so the child record could be inserted before the parent.

Also, for identity columns on the tables, you cannot retrieve the identity value from one stream and use it in another without using subsequent merge joins.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do that, is by using Lookup Transformation to get the ID for each value. You must be aware that duplicates may lead to a problem, you have to make sure that the value is not found multiple times in the foreign tables.

Also, make sure to redirect rows that have no match into a staging table to check them later.

You can refer to the following article for a step by step guide to Lookup Transformation:

- [An Overview of the LOOKUP TRANSFORMATION in SSIS](https://www.sqlshack.com/an-overview-of-the-lookup-transformation-in-ssis/)

Comment: I found this very helpful. I had concerns of performance but with half a million records, it was a breeze. http://www.techbrothersit.com/2014/09/ssis-how-to-use-flat-file-or-excel-file.html